What is the spatial average of a traceless $3\times3$ tensor?
Given is a traceless $3\times3$ tensor $\bf T$ with three real eigenvalues. (Their sum is thus zero.) We are in 3d Euclidean space.

If one averages the product $\bf u T$ over all possible unit vectors $\bf u$, is the average given by $\bf u$?

What is the average of the product $\bf u T u$ over all unit vectors $\bf u$?


It seems to me that there must be a simple analogy that allows answering this, but I do not see which one...
(Of course, this is not homework.)

The components of $uT$ are linear combinations of the components of $u$. Isn't the average with $u$ ranging over the sphere then automatically zero?

Similarly with the quadratic $uTu$. The average of $u_iu_j$ over the sphere is zero whenever $i\neq j$. For reasons of symmetry. The sum of the diagonal terms remains,...

I suspect so too, I just cannot give a clean argument.

May be this is a suitable duplicate target? It is over the entire ball rather than just the spherical surface, but... Anyway, I would expect older posts with the same theme to exist in abundance :-(

Let $S$ be the unit sphere and $\mu$ the measure on it uniquely determined by requiring that it is invariant under orthogonal transformations from $O_3(\Bbb{R})$, and the normalization $\mu(S)=1$.
So both $\mu$ and $S$ are invariant under the reflections w.r.t. a coordinate plane that changes the sign of a single coordinate. This immediately implies that
$$\int_S x_i\,d\mu=0$$
for all $i=1,2,3$, and
$$\int_S x_ix_j\,d\mu=0$$
whenever $i\neq j$. As seen e.g. here, it also follows that $\int_S x_i^2\,d\mu=1/3$.
In the question the components of $uT$ are linear combinations of the form $a_1u_1+a_2u_2+a_3u_3$. By the above observations the integral $\int_SuT\,d\mu$ automatically vanishes.
For its part $uTu$ is a sum of terms of the form $t_{ij}u_iu_j$. Again, whenever
$i\neq j$, the integral over $S$ vanishes. That leaves
$$E(uTu)=\int_S\sum_{i=1}^3t_{ii}u_i^2\,\,d\mu=\frac13(t_{11}+t_{22}+t_{33}).$$
Because the trace was assumed to vanish, so does this integral.

Will delete, when a suitable duplicate is found. I don't frequent these tags, so my search-fu is correspondingly weaker. There is this, but we need something simpler.
